# How to link Cublas library with CMake CUDA 10.0 Ubuntu 18

Tags: cmake, cuda, linker, cublas

The following code is about my CMakeList file and it can work well on CUDA 9.2 Ubuntu 14. However, when I try to run it on our new server, I get error message.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O2 -std=c++11")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O2")
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(LMM)
set(DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/include)
find_package(GSL REQUIRED)
find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)
find_package(CUDA)
if (CUDA_FOUND)
    message("CUDA found")
else()
    message("CUDA not found, doing something alternatively")
endif()

include_directories(test_cuda PRIVARE
                    ${GSL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    ${BLAS_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    ${CUDA_CUBLAS_DIRS}
                    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(GPU_LMM main.cpp aux.cpp)
target_link_libraries( GPU_LMM  PRIVATE
                        ${GSL_LIBRARY}
                        ${BLAS_LIBRARIES}
                        ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
```

The log information is as the following.

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Found GSL: /usr/include (found version "2.4") 
-- Looking for sgemm_
-- Looking for sgemm_ - found
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- A library with BLAS API found.
-- Found CUDA: /usr/local/cuda (found version "10.0") 
CUDA found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

However, when I run my program, I the the following error message.

```
aux.cpp:(.text+0x28d1): undefined reference to `cublasSetVector'
aux.cpp:(.text+0x290e): undefined reference to `cublasSetMatrix'
aux.cpp:(.text+0x2942): undefined reference to `cublasSetMatrix'
aux.cpp:(.text+0x2994): undefined reference to `cublasSgemv_v2'
aux.cpp:(.text+0x29e0): undefined reference to `cublasSgemv_v2'
aux.cpp:(.text+0x2a32): undefined reference to `cublasSgemv_v2'
aux.cpp:(.text+0x2a6c): undefined reference to `cublasSaxpy_v2'
aux.cpp:(.text+0x2b4a): undefined reference to `cublasSetMatrix'
aux.cpp:(.text+0x2bed): undefined reference to `cublasSgemv_v2'
aux.cpp:(.text+0x2c3c): undefined reference to `cublasSgemv_v2'
aux.cpp:(.text+0x2c7c): undefined reference to `cublasScopy_v2'
aux.cpp:(.text+0x2cb4): undefined reference to `cublasSaxpy_v2'
aux.cpp:(.text+0x2d1e): undefined reference to `cublasSgemv_v2'
aux.cpp:(.text+0x2d6a): undefined reference to `cublasSgemv_v2'
aux.cpp:(.text+0x2dbc): undefined reference to `cublasSgemv_v2'
aux.cpp:(.text+0x2df6): undefined reference to `cublasSaxpy_v2'
aux.cpp:(.text+0x2e25): undefined reference to `cublasGetVector'
aux.cpp:(.text+0x2e50): undefined reference to `cublasGetVector'
```

I make sure that I have installed the Cublas on server, because I can reproduce the official Cublas demo. When I add the `CUDA_CUBLAS_LIBRARIES`, I get the following error.

```
-- A library with BLAS API found.
CUDA found
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CUDA_cublas_device_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "GPU_LMM" in directory /home/szhangcj/C++/LMM

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: According to [documenation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDA.html), the variable `CUDA_LIBRARIES` contains only *core* CUDA libraries, not for Cublas. In your previous (deleted) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54341883/cmake-how-to-link-cublas-on-cuda-10-0) you have tried `CUDA_CUBLAS_LIBRARIES` variable, and this seems to be the right direction. The documentation also suggests `CUDA_ADD_CUBLAS_TO_TARGET` macro for link cublas.

Comment: Note, that your setting for `CMAKE_*_FLAGS` variables has no effect, as they are located **before** the `project()` call, which changes content of these variables.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Well, thank you for your explanation. I try to add "CUDA_CUBLAS_LIBRARIES" in my CMakeList file, however, I cannot find the Cublas properly. I also try to use "CUDA_ADD_CUBLAS_TO_TARGET" and I get the error something that the target variable has been used.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Although I tried "CUDA_CUBLAS_LIBRARIES", I cannot link the cublas properly.

Comment: "I cannot find the Cublas properly", "I get the error something that the target variable has been used", "I cannot link the cublas properly" - It is difficult to help with such vague descriptions. Show the **exact error messages**, as you did in your deleted post.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script [FindCUDA.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.13.0/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake) for recent CMake versions (e.g., 13.0) knows, that the library `cublas_device` is no longer used since CUDA 9.2, and the script does not search that library.

As your error message notes `cublas_device` library, it means that your `FindCUDA.cmake` script is **too old**, and it cannot work with newest CUDA versions.

For correctly use `find_package(CUDA)` with newest CUDA version you need to update your CMake.

Comment: Thank you. So what is the simplest way for me to include both cublas and other libraries such as GSL?

Comment: If you don't want to update CMake, you may explicitely add required libraries (like `cublas`) to the `target_link_libraries()` call.

Comment: When I add the cublas to my "target_link_libraries()", I get the following error.main.cpp:32:5: error: ‘cublasHandle_t’ was not declared in this scope
     cublasHandle_t handle;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Eh? Linking libraries shouldn't affect compilation stage. Looks like you have problems with your C++ code.

Comment: There is no error with my C++ code. It can work well with Ubuntu 14 and CUDA 9.2. Thank you